# Update a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to update my array but it doesn't work as expected!

I got this array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => property_unit Object
            (
                [unit] => one bedroom
                [details] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => propertydetails Object
                            (
                                [priority] => 3
                                [size] => 54
                                [percentage] => 0
                                [search] => 1
                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => property_unit Object
            (
                [unit] => two bedroom
                [details] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => propertydetails Object
                            (
                                [priority] => 1
                                [size] => 74
                                [percentage] => 0
                                [search] => 1
                            )

                    )

            )

        [2] => property_unit Object
            (
                [unit] => three bedroom
                [details] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => propertydetails Object
                            (
                                [priority] => 1
                                [size] => 90
                                [percentage] => 0
                                [search] => 1
                            )

                    )

            )

        [3] => property_unit Object
            (
                [unit] => studio
                [details] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => propertydetails Object
                            (
                                [priority] => 2
                                [size] => 22.35
                                [percentage] => 0
                                [search] => 1
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => property_unit Object
            (
                [unit] => one bedroom
                [details] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => propertydetails Object
                            (
                                [priority] => 3
                                [size] => 54
                                [percentage] => 0
                                [search] => 1
                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => property_unit Object
            (
                [unit] => two bedroom
                [details] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => propertydetails Object
                            (
                                [priority] => 1
                                [size] => 74
                                [percentage] => 0
                                [search] => 1
                            )

                    )

            )

        [2] => property_unit Object
            (
                [unit] => studio
                [details] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => propertydetails Object
                            (
                                [priority] => 2
                                [size] => 22.35
                                [percentage] => 0
                                [search] => 1
                            )

                    )

            )

        [3] => property_unit Object
            (
                [unit] => three bedroom
                [details] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => propertydetails Object
                            (
                                [priority] => 1
                                [size] => 90
                                [percentage] => 0
                                [search] => 1
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => property_unit Object
            (
                [unit] => one bedroom
                [details] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => propertydetails Object
                            (
                                [priority] => 3
                                [size] => 54
                                [percentage] => 0
                                [search] => 1
                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => property_unit Object
            (
                [unit] => three bedroom
                [details] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => propertydetails Object
                            (
                                [priority] => 1
                                [size] => 90
                                [percentage] => 0
                                [search] => 1
                            )

                    )

            )

        [2] => property_unit Object
            (
                [unit] => two bedroom
                [details] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => propertydetails Object
                            (
                                [priority] => 1
                                [size] => 74
                                [percentage] => 0
                                [search] => 1
                            )

                    )

            )

        [3] => property_unit Object
            (
                [unit] => studio
                [details] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => propertydetails Object
                            (
                                [priority] => 2
                                [size] => 22.35
                                [percentage] => 0
                                [search] => 1
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
)
```

and using var_dump()

```
array (size=24)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => 
        object(property_unit)[1]
          public 'unit' => string 'one bedroom' (length=11)
          public 'details' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      1 => 
        object(property_unit)[3]
          public 'unit' => string 'two bedroom' (length=11)
          public 'details' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      2 => 
        object(property_unit)[5]
          public 'unit' => string 'three bedroom' (length=13)
          public 'details' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      3 => 
        object(property_unit)[7]
          public 'unit' => string 'studio' (length=6)
          public 'details' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => 
        object(property_unit)[1]
          public 'unit' => string 'one bedroom' (length=11)
          public 'details' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      1 => 
        object(property_unit)[3]
          public 'unit' => string 'two bedroom' (length=11)
          public 'details' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      2 => 
        object(property_unit)[7]
          public 'unit' => string 'studio' (length=6)
          public 'details' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      3 => 
        object(property_unit)[5]
          public 'unit' => string 'three bedroom' (length=13)
          public 'details' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => 
        object(property_unit)[1]
          public 'unit' => string 'one bedroom' (length=11)
          public 'details' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      1 => 
        object(property_unit)[5]
          public 'unit' => string 'three bedroom' (length=13)
          public 'details' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      2 => 
        object(property_unit)[3]
          public 'unit' => string 'two bedroom' (length=11)
          public 'details' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      3 => 
        object(property_unit)[7]
          public 'unit' => string 'studio' (length=6)
          public 'details' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
  3 =>
```

I got this array with this:

```
$array = [new property_unit('one bedroom', [new propertydetails(1, 54, 0, 1)]),
    new property_unit('two bedroom', [new propertydetails(1, 74, 0, 1)]),
        new property_unit('three bedroom', [new propertydetails(1, 90, 0, 1)]),
            new property_unit('studio', [new propertydetails(2, 22.35, 0, 1)])];
```

Then I perform a computation on it to get all the possible array.

```
function computePermutations($array) {
    $result = [];

    $recurse = function($array, $start_i = 0) use (&$result, &$recurse) {
        if ($start_i === count($array)-1) {
            array_push($result, $array);
        }

        for ($i = $start_i; $i < count($array); $i++) {
            //Swap array value at $i and $start_i
            $t = $array[$i]; 
            $array[$i] = $array[$start_i]; 
            $array[$start_i] = $t;

            //Recurse
            $recurse($array, $start_i + 1);

            //Restore old order
            $t = $array[$i]; 
            $array[$i] = $array[$start_i]; 
            $array[$start_i] = $t;
        }
    };

    $recurse($array);

    return $result;
}
//I assign to my array
$array = computePermutations($array);
```

*I thing something maybe goes wrong here ?*

but when I'm trying to update my array like :

```
$array[0][0]->details[0]->priority = 3;
```

It update all the first priority field, (see the array before) this is after the update.

Meaning:

```
$array[0][0]->details[0]->priority
$array[1][0]->details[0]->priority
$array[2][0]->details[0]->priority
```

etc... becomes 3

Any idea where this can come from, is there any other way to update a multidimensional array? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What you expect after correct update array?

Comment: and how do you put those objects to array?

Comment: To access the data do `$array[$i][$j]->property_unit->details[$k]->propertydetails->priority`

Comment: Something is wrong with you ARRAY ouput. Did that come from `var_dump()` or `print_r()` or what?

Comment: It comes from a print_r(), what's wrong ?

Comment: make `var_dump` of the final `$array` in order to sure you got referenced objects there.

Comment: I just added the var_dump of the final array, do you have any idea of the problem ? Thanks

Comment: Have in mind that if you `array_push()` some object into an array, You are pushing the reference to the object, not the copy of the object. You may want to clone the object first.